# Get Id value for session storage JS/HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the value of my `myInput` id assigned to `sessionStorage.setItem`.
I used the function `document.getElementById("myInput").value`. When I display the `myInput` for `sessionStorage.setItem` there it gives me nothing.

How can I assign the value to the sessionstorage,

Any help would be appreciated!

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/4wvmsnbp/2/

Answer (score 1):

You have called two functions in the onClick attribute. **But the syntax is wrong!**

Correct Syntax is :

```
onclick="fun1(); fun2();"
```

Change the following :

```
<button onclick="myfilter(), mydisplay();">Filter</button>
```

To this:

```
<button onclick="myfilter(); mydisplay();">Filter</button>
```

This will now satisfy your requirement! 
Working Fiidle: [Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4wvmsnbp/11/)

Comment: Is there any problem with my answer? If you didn't got what you're looking for, then please comment here. So that we can update the code! I think the above code satisfies your requirement. Please run the code and make sure it is what you're looking for.